# Возможна ли реализация свойств, методов и полей в interface по умолчанию в Unity?

Tags: c#, unity3d

Я хотел реализовать interface в unity а в нём свойства с реализацией по умолчанию (ещё хотелось бы и поля, но я так понял в интерфейсах можно только статические и константы определять). Но получаю ошибку:

Целевая среда выполнения не поддерживает реализацию интерфейса по умолчанию.

Покопался, и наткнулся в комментах вот [здесь](https://metanit.com/sharp/tutorial/3.49.php), что реализация по умолчанию возможна только в NET Core (version 3.x) и .NET Standard (version 2.1) Покопался ещё и так понял, что в unity нельзя включить эти версии (вроде вот [здесь](https://docs.unity3d.com/2019.1/Documentation/Manual/dotnetProfileSupport.html) об этом написано).

И что, всё? Никак нельзя реализовать ни методы, ни свойства, ни поля в интерфейсах для unity?

Comment: Если с интерфейсами не получается, почему бы не использовать абстрактный класс? Вообще Default Interface Methods - весьма спорная фича.

Comment: На данный момент я так и сделал: воспользовался абстрактным классом. Просто мне кажется, с интерфейсами получилось бы более гибко, в силу того, что к одному классу их можно прикрутить несколько.

Comment: Там есть еще [веселый баг](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64295242/unexpected-behavior-of-a-c-sharp-8-0-default-interface-member) в .NET, будьте осторожны.